# Forcing ExitNodes fails for specific country

Tags: ip-address

I use Tor Browser 10.0.5 with Ubunto 16.04.

I am trying to configure my IP to be in a specific country with setting `ExitNodes {countryCode}` in `Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc`.

While for almost all countries it works fine (google is shown in language of desired country), when I set it to Israel (`{il}`) I get timeout.
Any idea why does it happen and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no exits in Israel (or at least with the `il` country code):
https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#search/country:il%20flag:exit

*Updated link to show only exit relays.*

Comment: With the query you shared I get 7 entries.... :-|

Comment: @guyaloni Those are not exit nodes (they don't have the exit flag).